# Поиск и выборка файла по названию

Tags: php

Сложная задача.

Есть каталог **pay**, в нём лежат файлы вида 1900_0.html, 1544_0.html, 1645_0.html, и.т.д. Имя файла строится по времени создания чека, то есть если чек в кассе выбит в 19:00, то файл будет называться 1900_0.html, и соответственно другие названия.

Мне нужно на сайте сделать блок "Сейчас покупают", а именно.

Есть массив файлов

```
$files=scandir('pay');
```

Есть текущее время

```
$date = $date = date('Hi');
```

Мне нужно в массиве файлов найти файл file_exist('pay/'.$date.'_0.html'); соответствующий текущему времени. А если его нет, то найти другой файл, но не позже текущего времени.

Как это сделать? Под конец рабочего дня мозг отказывается воспринимать, а скоро проект сдавать.))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается всё было просто, как молекула воды.

```
<?php
$date = (date('H')+11).date('i');
$files = scandir('pay');unset($files[0]);unset($files[1]);
$data = array();

foreach($files as $f)
{
    if(substr($f,0,4)<=$date)
    {
        $data[] = $f;
    }
}

$last = (count($data)-1);
$file = $data[$last];

echo($file);
?>
```

Вот так! :)

Comment: Вы делаете лишнею нагрузку, так как в часе 60 минут

Comment: Но я ведь не по массиву времени прохожусь, а по массиву файлов. там итераций цикла будет не больше чем файлов. Какая тут нагрузка?!

Answer (score 3):

Если правильно понял можно:

```
<?php 
    $h = date('H');
    $m = date('i');
    $limit = 1000; // чтобы сервер не встал
    if(!file_exist('pay/'.$h.$m.'_0.html')){
        while(!file_exist('pay/'.$h.$m.'_0.html') and $limit != 0){
            if($m == 0){
                $m = 60;
                $h--;
            }
            $m--;
        $limit--;
        }
        if($limit == 0)
            echo "Превышено количество проверок.";
        else
            $file = 'pay/'.$h.$m.'_0.html';
    }else
        $file = 'pay/'.$h.$m.'_0.html'
?>
```

$LIMIT -переменная какая отвечает, чтобы сервер не встал(завис).